# EJB asynchronous call not returning control to caller

Tags: java, asynchronous, jboss

I'm making calls to an asynchronous EJB method from another EJB.
This method has a heavy load (database operations) so it should return the control to the caller and do the bussiness in a separated thread.

According to the API, this should be the way to do it:

Remote interface:

```
@Remote
public interface MyEJBRemote {

    @Asynchronous
    void myMethod() throws RuntimeException;
}
```

EJB class:

```
@LocalBean
@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NEVER)
public class MyEJB implements MyEJBRemote {

    @Override
    public void myMethod() throws RuntimeException {
        //for testing
        while (true){
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            logger.info("Running asynchronous method");
        }
        //Method code here
    }
}
```

Caller code:

```
@LocalBean
@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NEVER)
public class MyEJBCaller {

    @EJB
    private MyEJB myEJB;

    public void request() throws RuntimeException {
        logger.info("Begin");
        myEJB.myMethod();
        logger.info("End");
    }
}
```

For testing purposes I have created an infinite loop inside the asynchronous method.
In theory, in the log should appear "Begin"-"End"-"Running asynchronous method"
but it never reach the "End".

I'm missing something? Why the call to the method doesn't return the controll to the caller?

I'm using a JBoss EAP 6.4 server. Can it be a configuration problem in the server side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't figured out the problem, but i got a solution if someone else is having the same issue: Remove the annotations from the remote interface and put them in the EJB itself.

The interface:

```
@Remote
public interface MyEJBRemote {

    void myMethod() throws RuntimeException;
}
```

The EJB:

```
@LocalBean
@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NEVER)
public class MyEJB implements MyEJBRemote {

    @Override
    @Asynchronous
    public void myMethod() throws RuntimeException {
        //for testing
        while (true){
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            logger.info("Running asynchronous method");
        }
        //Method code here
    }
}
```

The caller:

```
@LocalBean
@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NEVER)
public class MyEJBCaller {

    @EJB
    private MyEJB myEJB;

    public void request() throws RuntimeException {
        logger.info("Begin");
        myEJB.myMethod();
        logger.info("End");
    }
}
```

Searching in the API for [Asynchronous](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Asynchronous.html) it seems that the target can be either a METHOD or a [TYPE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.html), so in theory the annotation can be declared in an interface. But maybe if the call is made from another local EJB the JVM only resolves it from the class, not the interface (as the annotation is resolved at runtime)

Tried also creating a local interface (instead of the remote) and got the same result, so it really seems that local calls need to define the annotation in the EJB method itself

**EDIT: The problem is that EJB doesn't inherit the annotation from the interface. This seems to be to avoid a multiple-inheritance problem**

Answer (score 0):

You should inject with ejb interface.

```
@LocalBean
@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NEVER)
public class MyEJBCaller {

    @EJB
    private MyEJBRemote myEJB;

    public void request() throws RuntimeException {
        logger.info("Begin");
        myEJB.myMethod();
        logger.info("End");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!
Tried that, but i still get the same result. Even if the EJB has a remote interface, the call is made from the local app. Maybe that's the problem?